# SQL Date Range using two columns

Tags: sql, hive

I have two columns in Hive table namely `dt` and `hr`, I want to get dt and hr between two given dt's and hr values

For Example : dt='2019-01-10' and '2019-01-15' so I want to get the dt ranges So I will query like `select * from table_name where dt >='2019-01-10' and dt<='2019-01-15';`how to achieve the same with one more column `hr` something like below:

`select * from table_name where (dt >='2019-01-10' and hr >='05') and (dt<='2019- 
01-15' and hr <='15')`;

But the above query doesn't work as expected which returns hr>='05' for all the dates But I want all the hr(00 to 23) for the dates in between 2019-01-10 and 2019-01-15

Comment: Have one timestamp column instead of separate date and hour columns.

Comment: @jarlh, its actually a partition columns `dt` and `hr`

Comment: @Vignesh do you really have `hr >=05` without quotes and `hr <='15'` with quotes, or is it a copy/paste typo? And what is the data type of `hr`?

Comment: @forpas,hr is String. Question Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check 3 conditions combined by `or`.
If `dt` is `'2019-01-10'` then `hr` must be `>= '05'`.
If `dt` is `'2019-01-15'` then `hr` must be `<= '15'`.
For any other `dt` between `'2019-01-10'` (exclusive) and `'2019-01-15'` (exclusive) 
the value of `hr` should not be checked.

```
select * 
from table_name 
where 
  (dt ='2019-01-10' and hr >= '05') 
  or
  (dt ='2019-01-15' and hr <= '15')
  or
  (dt > '2019-01-10' and dt < '2019-01-15')
```

Alternative solution:

```
select * 
from table_name 
where 
  concat(dt, ' ', hr) >= concat('2019-01-10', ' ', '05') 
  and
  concat(dt, ' ', hr) <= concat('2019-01-15', ' ', '15')
```

If you can use `between` it's even better:

```
select * 
from table_name 
where 
  concat(dt, ' ', hr) between 
  concat('2019-01-10', ' ', '05') and concat('2019-01-15', ' ', '15')
```

Comment: Thank you, the alternative solution worked for me..!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a condition for those days without hr restriction:

```
select * from table_name
where ((dt >= '2019-01-10' and hr >= '05') and (dt <= '2019-01-15' and hr <='15'))
   or (dt > '2019-01-10' and dt < '2019-01-15')
```

Or, does Hive perhaps support "Row and table constructors":

```
select * from table_name
where (dt, hr) >= ('2019-01-10', '05') and (dt, hr) <= ('2019-01-15', '15')
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you add a new column and join the dt and hr

update #tab set datetime1= CAST(CONCAT(date1, ' ', time1) AS DATETIME2(7))

Later you can select the datetime range from this newly added column.

If you dont want to add any new column to your table, insert the values in your table to a temp table and join the date time in that temp table.